# How can I disable opening info.php files?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that has multiple PHP files with the same name, like this:

> martin/info.php 
>   david/info.php 
>   peter/info.php

How can I disable opening info.php files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess file :

```
<FilesMatch "info\.php$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```